# How to get the time in python on android?

Tags: android, python, time, kivy, clock

I am trying to make a program that will use the time and display it down to the seconds. How do I do this?
So far I have found the function get_time() that is part of kivy but I am not sure how to use it. I have imported everything but it still says "not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

that should work on any python framework.

you can use the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for more details.